# What is the best way to query million records with aggregate GROUP in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, indexing, aggregate-functions

I would like to ask about the best way to query million record with aggregate GROUP in mongoDB.
now I have my project that storing log in everyday and there are a lot of record per day to storing

this this my doc structure

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5dfca2db3e58065c787cf821"),
    "product_id" : 47,
    "site_id" : 404,
    "b_id" : 587,
    "domain" : "google.com",
    "updated_at" : ISODate("2019-12-20T10:30:51Z"),
    "created_at" : ISODate("2019-12-20T10:30:51Z")
}
```

In my report, I would like to group by `product_id` and `created_at`to see how many product in each day. this below is my mongo query

```
[
    {
        '$match': [
            'created_at': [
                '$gte' => new DateTime(startDate),
                '$lte' => new DateTime(endDate),
            ],
        ],
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: {
                'product_id': product_id, 
                'date': {
                    $dateToString: {
                        date: '$created_at', 
                        format: '%Y-%m-%d'
                    }
                },
                'sum': {
                    '$sum': 1
                }
            }  
        }
]
```

now in my collections, there are 10million records and it took about `30sec` to done query.

with `explain()`

```
"stages" : [
    {
        "$cursor" : {
            "query" : {

            },
            "fields" : {
                "created_at" : 1,
                "product_id" : 1,
                "_id" : 0
            },
            "queryPlanner" : {
                "plannerVersion" : 1,
                "namespace" : "site_db.doc_47",
                "indexFilterSet" : false,
                "parsedQuery" : {

                },
                "winningPlan" : {
                    "stage" : "COLLSCAN",
                    "direction" : "forward"
                },
                "rejectedPlans" : [ ]
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "$group" : {
            "_id" : {
                "product_id" : "$product_id",
                "date" : {
                    "$dateToString" : {
                        "date" : "$created_at",
                        "format" : {
                            "$const" : "%Y-%m-%d"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "sum" : {
                    "$const" : 1
                }
            }
        }
    }
],
```

I already create index to collections but it seems not different.

so, my question is,

1. is it possible to make query is faster or how can we improve my query?
2. my doc structure is good to storing million record data?
3. any tool that better than mongodb?

Comment: What indexes do you have on the collection? Is it a _mongo shell_ query?

Comment: @prasad_ correct. `db.getCollection('doc_name').createIndex({product_id: 1})`

Comment: The index may not be useful in your query. An index on the `created_at` can be useful. If yu can, create an index on the date field and run the query with `explian()` and it generates a _query plan_. Post the _query plan_ output.

Comment: Hi @prasad_ I just create Index with created_at and updated `explain()` in my post. 

it seems not different, thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

What I would suggest is create another collection which stores only the summary you need.You can create a batch job or realtime streaming application which populates this collection instead of running expensive queries on your raw data store

Comment: seem to be a creative way

Answer (score 1):

> 1. is it possible to make query is faster or how can we improve my query?

Yes.

For the aggregation query to use indexes the index must be created for the fields used in the `$match` stage filter. So, create an index on the `created_at` field:

```
db.test.createIndex( { created_at: 1 } )
```

The query (with some syntax corrections):

```
var startDate = ISODate("2019-12-20T10:00:00Z") , endDate = ISODate("2019-12-22T10:00:00Z")

db.test.aggregate(
[
    {
        $match: {
            created_at: {
                $gte: startDate,
                $lte: endDate,
            },
        },
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: {
                product_id: "$product_id", 
                date: { $dateToString: {
                               format: "%Y-%m-%d",
                               date: "$created_at"
                } }
            },
            sum: {
                $sum: 1
            }
        }
    }
] )
```

If you generate a *query plan* using the `explain` method, you will see that the index is used:

```
"stage" : "IXSCAN"
"indexName" : "created_at_1"
```

And, this query is going to be a faster query with the index on `created_at`.

> 2. my doc structure is good to storing million record data?

There is no issues with the document structure, in general. You have to understand what fields you want in the document. The queries you are going to make on the collection should tell what details are to be in the document.

> 3. any tool that better than mongodb?

There are, may be (I don't have any info about that now).